# GQL Projection Query on Embedded Entity

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

Say I have a User entity with an embedded entity address which contains a house number property and a street property. How can I write a GQL projection query that will filter based on name and return a list of addresses ?

Sample Data:
[image: Sample Data]

The projection query I am trying to write:

```
SELECT address FROM User WHERE name = Bob
```

This should return two addresses but it returns no results.

Thanks to anyone who answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't project the entire entity value, but you can project the individual properties in the entity value, e.g.:

```
SELECT address.houseNumber FROM User WHERE name = Bob
```

Comment: What would be the best way to get the entire entity value ? Do I just project all the individual properties separately and combine them together afterwards ?

Comment: Either that or use a regular (non-projection) query.

Comment: @EdDavisson, what would be an example of a regular (non-projection) query?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM User WHERE name = Bob`